# Django Admin - How to pull model default field values from other tables

Tags: django, admin

I am trying to get a field value automatically pulled from different table. Below is my case: I have two tables: sales and returns. While entering a new return, when a "sales_id" is selected, want to show "sales_quantity" automatically populated, non-editable (and also if possible, want to constraint the "return_quantity" <= "sales_quantity").

```
class T_Sales(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(P_Product)
    sales_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return str(self.id)

class T_Return(models.Model):
    sales_id = models.ForeignKey(T_Sales)
    #sales_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=T_Sales.sales_quantity)
    return_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return self.description
```

Comment: Where? In the built-in admin? In your own view? In a template?

Comment: You shouldn't name your foreign fields with `_id` suffix, it just looks bad. Django will actually create new field with `_id` and store raw ID here (that field is saved into database) and field created directly by foreign key will retrieve foreign object (it is not saved into database). Adding `_id` will end up creating `sales_id_id` in database.

Answer (score 0):

Creating property in your model will do the job. `sales_id` won't be null, so there will never be an issue when trying to get that value.

```
class T_Sales(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(P_Product)
    sales_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return str(self.id)

class T_Return(models.Model):
    sales_id = models.ForeignKey(T_Sales)
    return_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return self.description

    @property
    def sales_quantity(self):
        return self.sales_id.sales_quantity
```

Pros of that method:

- value is not stored in your database twice
- value will be automatically updated if there is change on `T_Sales` object.

Cons of that method:

- It will trigger separate query when fetching that field, unless use `select_related` in your queryset.
- it is hard (but possible) to print that field in detail view inside django admin (you can always show it only on list).

If you wan't to create some validation, you can override model's `clean` method and do your comparsion here, if there is something wrong, you should throw `ValidationError`. Example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class T_Return(models.Model):

    # ......

    def clean(self):
        if self.return_quantity > self.sales_quantity:
            raise ValidationError("You can't return more than it was bought")
        return super(T_Return, self).clean()
```

You can also assign error to `return_quantity` field, just pass dict in form `'field_name': error` into validation error:

```
            raiseValidationError({'return_quantity': _('You can't return more than it was bought.')}
```

You can't assign that error to `sales_quantity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate field in `T_Return` model and copy value from `T_Sales` on save:

```
class T_Sales(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(P_Product)
    sales_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return str(self.id)

class T_Return(models.Model):
    sales_id = models.ForeignKey(T_Sales)
    sales_quantity = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
    return_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return self.description

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.sales_quantity:
            self.sales_quantity = self.sales_id.sales_quantity
        supr(T_Return, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Pros of that method:

- It will trigger additional query to `T_Sales` only on (first) save.
- It is easy to display value in admin's detail view

Cons of that method:
 - You're storing value in database twice
 - If value in `T_Sales` object will change, value in `T_Return` won't be changed automatically (that can be fixed by simple trigger on save of `T_Sales`, but only inside django ORM)

If you wan't to create some validation, you can override model's `clean` method and do your comparsion here, if there is something wrong, you should throw `ValidationError`. Example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class T_Return(models.Model):

    # ......

    def clean(self):
        if self.return_quantity > self.sales_quantity:
            raise ValidationError("You can't return more than it was bought")
        return super(T_Return, self).clean()
```

You can also assign error to `return_quantity` or to `sales_quantity` field, just pass dict in form `'field_name': error` into validation error:

```
            raiseValidationError({'return_quantity': _('You can't return more than it was bought.')}
```

Assigning that errot both to `return_quantity` and `sales_quantity` will show that error twice.