# Default field value from one model equals to a field from another model

Tags: django, django-models

Original question unanswered: [Django Admin - How to pull model default field values from other tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731295/django-admin-how-to-pull-model-default-field-values-from-other-tables)

I want to have 2 models in admin panel, first one with random fields and another one which will server to change defaults for the first one.
How can it be done?

Comment: It's not quite clear what do you want. Exactly the same as in original question, so that the default value of some field in one model is equal to some field from another model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set a default value from one field equal to the field from another model, since the default value should be fixed (an instance). Try to rewrite the save method. For example:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    city = models.CharField()
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.city = self.company.location
        super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```